# Javascript Regex Replace - Not replacing all the required strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I have no idea what is happening here..

```
model.attributes.data.Path.replace('/\\/g',""), @options.path.replace('/\\/g',"")
```

When doing :

```
console.log model.attributes.data.Path.replace('/\\/g',""), 
@options.path.replace('/\\/g',"")
```

the data is:

> T2/T2_2, T2/T2_2

It returns this:

> T2T2_2, T2/T2_2

So only the first path was replaced, but not the second one? Why would that be?

Comment: What was the input data?

Comment: it was T2/T2_2 , T2/T2_2

Comment: Sory, changed it, needs to be , not ==

Comment: no, thats not what I am doing. Im doing two replaces, its not one string. Im just logging them next to each other

Comment: 114 questions and did not learn how to format your code in your questions?

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the fact you're matching backslashes (`\\` = `\`), instead of forward slashes (`\/` = `/`), Don't put your regexes into the replace function as strings.

Use:

```
.replace(/\//g,"");
```

Instead of

```
.replace('/\//g',"");
```

Then it'll work just fine:

```
"T2/T2_2 , T2/T2_2".replace(/\//g,"");
// returns: "T2T2_2 , T2T2_2"
```

Otherwise, it'll just try to literally find the *string* `'/\//g'`.

Also, to replace both forward and backslashes in 1 regex, try this:

```
"T2/T2_2 , T2\T2_2".replace(/\/|\\/g,"");
// returns: "T2T2_2 , T2T2_2"

# \/|\\ Matches:
# \/  - Forward slash
# |   - Or
# \\  - Backslash
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
model.attributes.data.Path.replace(/\//g,"")
@options.path.replace(/\//g,"")
```

`/\\/g` matches a backslash and `/\//g` matches a forward slash.

Comment: That is actually the problem, I missed it and neglected to write it in the question. The first one contains a backslash and the second a forward. it was actually T2\T2_2 , T2/T2_2

Comment: @Harry, noticed, but only part of the problem :P

Answer (score 1):

Try `.replace(/\//g,"")` instead of `.replace('/\\/g',"")`, (the regex is not a string).